# Erro em consulta ao webservice CADSUS em PHP

Tags: php, web-service

Olá, pessoal.

Estou tentando consumir a função `"pesquisar"` do barramento CADSUS, porém recebo como resposta o erro

```
"Forced circuit exception";
```

O código utilizado segue abaixo, usando *Laravel 5.6* e *PHP 7.1*:

```
Route::get('/ws/teste', function () {
    try {
        $opts = array(
            'http' => array(
                'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient'
            )
        );
        $context = stream_context_create($opts);
        $wsdlUrl = 'https://servicoshm.saude.gov.br/cadsus/CadsusService/v5r0?wsdl';
        $soapClientOptions = array(
            'trace' => 1,
            'stream_context' => $context,
            'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
            'Username' => 'CADSUS.CNS.PDQ.PUBLICO',
            'Password' => 'kUXNmiiii#RDdlOELdoe00966'
        );
        $client = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, $soapClientOptions);
        $parameters = array(
            'CNESUsuario' => array(
                'CNES' => '6963447',
                'Usuario' => 'LEONARDO',
                'Senha' => ''
            ),
            'FiltroPesquisa' => array(
                'nomeCompleto' => 'SERGIO ARAUJO CORREIA LIMA',
                'tipoPesquisa' => 'IDENTICA'
            ),
            'higienizar' => 0
        );
        $result = $client->pesquisar($parameters);
        print_r($result);
    }
    catch(\Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    } });
```

Se alguém souber o que pode estar acontecendo, por favor, me ajude!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boa noite,
Tive um problema parecido e tive que alterar bastante seu codigo,
- a unica maneira que consegui autenticar foi enviando no header com os namespaces definidos no exemplo

- passa os dados com array da muito problema 'Encoding: object has no ', melhor passar por classe, segue abaixo codigo que funcionou pra mim.

```html
<?php
try {
    $wsdlUrl = 'https://servicoshm.saude.gov.br/cadsus/CadsusService/v5r0?wsdl';
    $wsUser = 'CADSUS.CNS.PDQ.PUBLICO';
    $passWs = 'kUXNmiiii#RDdlOELdoe00966';
    $soapClientOptions = array(
 'trace' => 1,
 'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
    );
    $client = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, $soapClientOptions);
    $xmlheader = '
<wsse:Security SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-F6C95C679D248B6E3F143032021465917">
        <wsse:Username>' . $wsUser . '</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">' . $passWs . '</wsse:Password>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
';
    $header = new SoapHeader('http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd', 'Security', new \SoapVar($xmlheader, XSD_ANYXML), false);
    $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

    $requestPesquisar = new stdClass();
    $requestPesquisar->CNESUsuario = new stdClass();
    $requestPesquisar->CNESUsuario->CNES = '6963447';
    $requestPesquisar->CNESUsuario->Usuario = 'LEONARDO';
    $requestPesquisar->CNESUsuario->Senha = '?';
    $requestPesquisar->FiltroPesquisa = new stdClass();
    $requestPesquisar->FiltroPesquisa->nomeCompleto = new stdClass();
    $requestPesquisar->FiltroPesquisa->nomeCompleto->Nome = 'SERGIO ARAUJO CORREIA LIMA';
    $requestPesquisar->FiltroPesquisa->tipoPesquisa = 'IDENTICA';
    $requestPesquisar->higienizar = '0';
    $result = $client->pesquisar($requestPesquisar);
    if ($result) {
 echo '<pre>', print_r($result), '</pre>';
    } else {
 echo '<h2>Request:</h2>';
 echo '<pre>', print_r($client->__getLastRequest()), '</pre>';
 echo '<h2>Header:</h2>';
 echo '<pre>', print_r($client->__getLastRequestHeaders()), '</pre>';
 echo '<h2>Response:</h2>';
 echo '<pre>', print_r($client->__getLastResponse()), '</pre>';
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo '<pre>', print_r($e), '<pre>';
}
?>
```

Busca Por CNS (Unica que retorna dados completos) Exemplo XML

```html
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:cad="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/cadsus/v5r0/cadsusservice" xmlns:cnes="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/wsdl/mensageria/v5r0/cnesusuario" xmlns:cns="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/schema/cadsus/v5r0/cns">
   <soap:Header>
   <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1" 
   xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
   xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-F6C95C679D248B6E3F143032021465917">
   <wsse:Username>CADSUS.CNS.PDQ.PUBLICO</wsse:Username>
   <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">kUXNmiiii#RDdlOELdoe00966</wsse:Password>
   </wsse:UsernameToken>
   </wsse:Security>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <cad:requestConsultar>
         <cnes:CNESUsuario>
            <cnes:CNES>?</cnes:CNES>
            <cnes:Usuario>?</cnes:Usuario>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <cnes:Senha>?</cnes:Senha>
         </cnes:CNESUsuario>
         <cns:CNS>
            <cns:numeroCNS>AQUI_NUMERO_CNS</cns:numeroCNS>
         </cns:CNS>
      </cad:requestConsultar>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: poderia colocar o codigo dentro da resposta, pois nao podemos confiar em links, uma vez  que possam ser cancelados no futuro

Comment: @UmProgramador ja inseri o codigo na resposta.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Muito obrigado! Só surgiu uma dúvida: mandar os dados de usuário e senha pelo xml header não sei uma falha de segurança? Se alguém estiver snifando a rede, não conseguiria capturar o pacote e visualizar?

Comment: Lucas Maia, não sei dizer se há problema de segurança mas acredito que não. e na especificação técnica pede para enviar assim, no exemplo da página 13 http://datasus.saude.gov.br/images/Interoperabilidade/Especificao%20Tecnica%20para%20Integracao%20CADSUS%20V5.pdf

Comment: Opa, @AndreRicardoAlvesDosSantos, muito obrigado mais uma vez!

Comment: complementando: descobri que para retornar os dados completos utilize a operação consultar do webservice informando somente o cartao sus. mas a estrutura tem que ser exata vou colocar na resposta inicial.